# Construct three subspaces $M$, $N_1$, and $N_2$ of a vector space V so that $M \oplus N_1 = M \oplus N_2$ but $N_1 \neq N_2$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Construct three subspaces $M$, $N_1$, and $N_2$ of a vector space $V$ so that $M \oplus N_1 = M \oplus N_2$ but $N_1 \neq N_2$. What is the geometric picture corresponding to this situation?

Comment: Think about $\Bbb R^3$. If $M$ is a plane, any straight line $r$ that meets it only in the origin satisfies $M\oplus r=\Bbb R^3$. But, of course, there are many such lines.

Answer (score 2):

Take $V = \mathbb{R}^2$, $M$ to be the $x$-axis, $N_1$ to be the $y$-axis, and $N_2$ to be the line $y=x$. Then this solves your problem.

Comment: how would I do it in a general case though? I understand the $R^2$ and $C^4$ cases but not generally. Thanks or your help.

Comment: Assuming your vector space is finite dimensional, and generalizing the above for any euclidean space, you may try to see the general case.